# Теория автоматов, синтезировать недетерминированный последовательный автомат

Tags: теория-автоматов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходима помощь,кто разбирается. Синтезировать недетерминированный последовательностный автомат-распознаватель кода при учете возможного изменения только одного двоичного входа в каждом такте. Элементная база-ОФПЭБ, RS-триггеры. ПОследовательность -13731.

Comment: Похоже, нужно показывать методичку или конспект лекций. Офпэб - что то местное, оно даже не гуглится. Имя преподавателя и вуза тоже желательно указать.

Comment: Добавил картинку, она с этого задания, может поможет

Comment: Не сильно оно помогает